# How can i use a timer in synchronization with background worker?

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker

I am using a background worker in an application to get data from hardware and updating in UI continuously. I need to configure hardware to get info from it. Here my requirement is to change the configuration of hardware for every 2 sec and need to update the corresponding info in UI. How can i achieve this with proper synchronization?

EDIT:
 here i am posting my logic:

```
         worker3.WorkerReportsProgress = true;        
        worker3.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker3.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker3_DoWork);
        worker3.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker3_ProcessChanged);
         DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
       timer.Tick += timer_tick;
        timer.Start();

        worker3.RunWorkerAsync();

  }
    private void worker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       // Here running infinite loop. In that loop
      // i am calling the function in dll which will get the data from harware. Passing info which  i got to process changed event
    } 
      private void worker3_ProcessChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Here updating the UI with the information which i got from hardware.
    }

    private void time_tick(object sender, EventArgs )
  {
    if(worker3.IsBusy==true) 
         worker3.CancelAsync();

    // Configuring hardware with new options.
    // Again start the Background worker
    if(worker3.IsBusy!=true)
       worker3.RunAsync(); 
  }
```

Comment: Any issue with your current logic?

Comment: _Here running infinite loop._ - that loop better break on CancellationPending.

Comment: ya .. i am using Cancellation Pending . Here i am Updating some wrong data in UI.